# PowerShell - Exception handling

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I´m searching for the best way to handling exceptions in PowerShell.
In the following example I want to create a new SharePoint web and remove a old SharePoint web. When the New-SPWeb fails, it is necessary that the script ends.
I think try/catch is the best way, because the "if" statement only checks if $a exists.
Are there still other options to handling exceptions?

Exception handling with "if" statement:

```
$a = New-SPWeb http://newspweb
if($a -eq $null)
{
Write-Error "Error!"
Exit
}
Write-Host "No Error!"
Remove-SPWeb http://oldspweb
```

With try/catch:

```
try
{
$a = New-SPWeb http://newspweb
}
catch
{
Write-Error "Error!"
Exit
}
Write-Host "No Error!"
Remove-SPWeb http://oldspweb
```

Comment: DON'T ever again use the term "if loop" or be prepared to have your developer status questioned. - SCNR

Comment: Sure a if statement is not a loop :-) I fixed it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try/catch is really for handling terminating errors and continuing on.  It sounds like you want to stop on a non-terminating error.  If that's the case, use the `ErrorAction` parameter on `New-SPWeb` and set it to `Stop` e.g.:

```
$a = New-SPWeb http://newspweb -ErrorAction Stop
```

This will convert the non-terminating error into a terminating error.

Comment: Thanks Keith. This paramter is really helpfull!

Comment: This parameter is one of several "common" parameters found on all cmdlets. Check out the associated help topic `man about_CommonParameters`.

Comment: Keith, I think you mean non-terminating errors.  Terminating errors will stop anyway.  :)

Comment: @JasonMArcher, OK misread your comment at first - yes, that was what I meant.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5):

Try catch is certainly the right way. But, it will catch only terminating errors. So, if `New-SPWeb` does not throw a terminating error, you can never catch it. I guess, it results in a terminating error.

BTW, if you want all details about the error, output `$_` in `catch {}.` It will have all error information.